# JavaScript Asynchronous Audio Debugging

Tags: javascript, html, url, audio, ecmascript-6

In my JavaScript audio player, I am experiencing asynchronous issues with the playback and the ads transitions. The audio playback and ad transition are sometimes buggy and too long. I need help debugging the code to improve the performance and fix any bugs. Specifically, I need assistance with the asynchronous aspects of the audio player code to ensure smooth transitions between songs and ads. The songs keep glitching and seems to run through the entire ads list.
It would be great if someone could help reproduce parts of my code using JavaScript, I am really stumped.

The code randomly selects a song from a list of songs and plays it on an HTML audio player. It also updates the artist and song information in the HTML elements for display purposes. If the song is about to end, it triggers an ad to play, and after the ad finishes, it selects another random song to play.

Here's a simple visual pseudo-code of the process:

```
WHILE program is running:
SELECT a random song from the song list
IF the song has been played recently:
SELECT another random song
ELSE:
ADD the song index to the previous songs list
IF the previous songs list has more than 10 entries:
REMOVE the oldest song index
UPDATE the artist and song information in the HTML elements
SET the audio player source to the URL of the selected song
PLAY the audio player

IF the remaining time of the current song is less than 4 seconds:
FADE OUT the audio player
SELECT a random ad from the ad list
SET the ad audio player source to the URL of the selected ad
PLAY the ad audio player
DISABLE the next song button
WHEN the ad audio player updates its time:
IF the remaining time of the ad is less than 4 seconds:
REMOVE the ad audio player event listener
SELECT a new random song to play
ENABLE the next song button
FADE IN the audio player
```

Here's the below JavaScript code (I have removed most of the contents of songs and ads variables for privacy):

```js
// Define the songs object with name, artist, and URL for each song
var songs = [{name: "Dance With Me Tonight", artist: "Olly Murs", url: "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview115/v4/77/3a/61/773a6178-430b-4d9a-0550-931da48b80cc/mzaf_16249376016298618799.plus.aac.ep.m4a"}];
var ads = [
{url:"https://d3q5dm8x5y8bx0.cloudfront.net/marketing/assets/audio/heart/1%20themes/HEART-HEART%202015-Theme%2007-Basic%20ID.mp3"}];
const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
const adAudio = document.getElementById('adAudio');
const playButton = document.getElementById('play');
const pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
const artistElement = document.getElementById('artist');
const songElement = document.getElementById('song');
const appleMusicAudioLink = document.getElementById('appleMusicLink');

let previousSongs = [];
let currentSongIndex;
let remainingTime;

function playRandomSong() {
  let randomSongIndex;
  do {
    randomSongIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
  } while (previousSongs.includes(randomSongIndex) || (previousSongs.length > 10 && randomSongIndex === currentSongIndex));

  previousSongs.push(randomSongIndex);
  if (previousSongs.length > 10) {
    previousSongs.shift();
  }

  currentSongIndex = randomSongIndex;

  const { artist, name, url } = songs[randomSongIndex];
  artistElement.textContent = artist;
  songElement.textContent = name;
  document.title = `${name} by ${artist}`;
  audio.src = url;

  appleMusicAudioLink.href = `https://music.apple.com/gb/search?term=${encodeURIComponent(name + ' ' + artist)}`;
}

function playAd() {
  fadeOut(audio, () => {
    artistElement.textContent = '--';
    songElement.textContent = '--';
    adAudio.src = ads[Math.floor(Math.random() * ads.length)].url;
    adAudio.play();
    document.title = 'Heart Radio - Ad';
    nextButton.disabled = true;

    adAudio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function onTimeUpdate() {
      const remainingAdTime = adAudio.duration - adAudio.currentTime;
      if (remainingAdTime < 4) {
        adAudio.removeEventListener('timeupdate', onTimeUpdate);
        playRandomSong();
        nextButton.disabled = false;
        fadeIn(audio);
      }
    });
  });
}

function fadeOut(audioElement, onEnd) {
  const interval = 250; // in milliseconds
  let volume = audioElement.volume;
  const fade = setInterval(() => {
    volume -= 0.1;
    if (volume <= 0) {
      clearInterval(fade);
      audioElement.volume = 0;
      audioElement.pause();
      onEnd?.();
    }
    audioElement.volume = volume;
  }, interval);
}

function fadeIn(audioElement) {
  const interval = 250; // in milliseconds
  let volume = 0.1;
  audioElement.play();
  const fade = setInterval(() => {
    volume += 0.1;
    if (volume >= 1) {
      clearInterval(fade);
    }
    audioElement.volume = volume;
  }, interval);
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!previousSongs.length) {
    playRandomSong();
  }
  audio.play();
  playButton.style.display = 'none';
  pauseButton.style.display = 'block';
});

pauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audio.pause();
  pauseButton.style.display = 'none';
  playButton.style.display = 'block';
});

nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  playRandomSong();
  audio.play();
  playButton.style.display = 'none';
  pauseButton.style.display = 'block';
});

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  remainingTime = audio.duration - audio.currentTime;
  if (remainingTime < 4) {
    playAd();
  }
});
```